# How to correctly set an URL calling a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using jslint to check my javascript.

It's giving me repeatedly the following error:

```
Problem at line 236 character 18: Script URL.
a.href = "javascript:DoSomething(" + messageID + ");"
```

Probably, jslint is right. What would be the correct way to set the .href?

Comment: Wow, the answers for this question are completely pointless.  #1 no one addressed your question.  #2 people are giving you really bad advice.  You should never use onclick.  JS handlers should be binded at the JS layer, not inline with onclicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it an `onclick` event handler instead, like this:

```
a.onclick = function() { DoSomething(messageID); };
```

Leave the `href` as `#` and either stop propgation or `return false` to stop the scroll, for example:

```
a.onclick = function() { DoSomething(messageID); return false; };
```

Comment: Thanks again for helping me with the basics :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `onclick` event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="DoSomething(messageID);">Link Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:DoSomething(" + messageID + "); return false;">Link</a>
```

I add the `return false;` to prevent the normal behavior of the `a`.

Comment: The leading "javascript:" is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

`HREF` should only be used for actual URLs. It is considered bad form to use "`href="javascript:...`".

An action calling JavaScript should go into the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you're trying to set "click" behavior by changing the "href" in the first place. Don't do that. Instead, give the `<a>` tag a "click" handler, and set the "href" to "#" if you don't want the link to "go' anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

to set: `document.getElementById('myHref').href = "http://stackoverflow.com"`